# Getting the first $n$ terms of a recursion relation

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

Given a recursion relation, I would like to generate the first $n$ terms (automatically) without having to go term by term.

---

***Background***

Each term is of the form $a_{n}(t)$, that is, $a_{n}$ is a function of $t$. However, $t$ does not appear explicitly - it appears as $f(t)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function of $t$. As such, the recurrence contains the times derivatives of $a_{n}(t)$ and $f(t)$.

We are given the first term, namely, $a_{0}(t)=1$.

---

In *Mathematica*, to compute $a_{1}(t)$, I do the following:

```
n=1;

a[0][t]=1;

Solve[(n + 1) (n - 4) (6 - n)*a[n][t]*D[f[t], t] == 
  -(n - 3) (n - 4)*D[a[n - 1][t], t] +
  12*Sum[D[a[k][t], t]*a[n - 1 - k][t], {k, 0, n - 1}] -
  12*Sum[(k - 2)*a[k][t]*a[n - k][t]*D[f[t], t], {k, 1, n - 1}],
  a[n][t]]
```

This gives $a_{1}(t)=0$. To compute the next term $a_{2}(t)$ I manually update the value of $n$ to $n=2$ and add the value of $a_{1}(t)$ together with $a_{0}(t)$.

```
n=2;
a[0][t]=1;
a[1][t]=0;

Solve[(n + 1) (n - 4) (6 - n)*a[n][t]*D[f[t], t] == 
  -(n - 3) (n - 4)*D[a[n - 1][t], t] +
  12*Sum[D[a[k][t], t]*a[n - 1 - k][t], {k, 0, n - 1}] -
  12*Sum[(k - 2)*a[k][t]*a[n - k][t]*D[f[t], t], {k, 1, n - 1}],
  a[n][t]]
```

I repeat the same procedure to find $a_{3}(t)$ and so on. This approach is quite tedious. Is there a way of generating the terms automatically instead of relying on the manual approach?

Comment: `a[3]` gives you zero. There is no solution for `a[4]` ... recheck your equations

Comment: The left hand side has the factor $(n+1)(n-4)(6-n)$ which becomes 0 for $n=4$ and $n=6$. Now, for $n=4$ the right hand side (which can be worked out because we know the previous values of $a_{n}(t)$) is also 0. This means that $a_{4}(t)$ is a free parameter. Similarly, $a_{6}(t)$ will turn out to be also a free parameter. Should I add this to the question? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @m_goldberg, Thanks for the edit (and the upvote). I can now start upvoting too :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want. Anyway:

```
a[0][t] = 1;
sol[4] = {a[4][t] -> a[4][t]}
sol[6] = {a[6][t] -> a[6][t]}
sol[n_] := sol[n] = First@Solve[
    (n + 1) (n - 4) (6 - n)*a[n][t]*
      D[f[t], t] == -(n - 3) (n - 4)*D[a[n - 1][t], t] + 
      12*Sum[D[a[k][t], t]*a[n - 1 - k][t], {k, 0, n - 1}] - 
      12*Sum[(k - 2)*a[k][t]*a[n - k][t]*D[f[t], t], {k, 1, n - 1}], 
    a[n][t]]

Table[a[n][t] = (a[n][t] /. sol[n]), {n, 1, 12}]
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 a(4)(t) \\
 \frac{5 a(4)'(t)}{3 f'(t)} \\
 a(6)(t) \\
 0 \\
 \frac{1}{3} (a(4)(t))^2 \\
 \frac{2 a(4)(t) a(4)'(t)}{3 f'(t)} \\
 \frac{18 a(4)(t) a(6)(t) f'(t)^2+25 \left(a(4)'(t)\right)^2}{66 f'(t)^2}
   \\
 \frac{a(6)(t) a(4)'(t)}{3 f'(t)} \\
 \frac{1}{39} \left(2 (a(4)(t))^3+3 (a(6)(t))^2\right) \\
\end{array}$

Comment: Thank you very much. I can easily find out which parameters are free without using Mathematica. So, this works perfectly for my case.